# copy button for input field and add URL automatic when its coped

Tags: javascript, html

i have input field and copy button, visitors can write their phone number inside the input (ex: +123456789) and then click copy button to copy the numbers.

i want the visitor when click copy and past it anywhere it should be with URL `example.com/123456789` so the URL add automatically and without (+) mark.

i have this code but it does not work as i expect and i tried to modified still not work.

```
<input type="text" id="phonenumber">

<div class="tooltip">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
  <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
  Copy text
  </button>
</div>
```

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("phonenumber");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied";
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
</script>
```

i've tried to do it like this
`var copyText = document.getElementById("example.com/","phonenumber");`
But its not working, i add extra var but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working example of the code:

[Codepen link (click to view live example)](https://codepen.io/preetsojitra/pen/GRGwYpw)

Used `string.substring(1)` to remove the first character from the input text. Then simply added it to clipboard by appending `example.com` to it while writing it to clipboard

Comment: thank you so much, the code works great but the (+) still in the coped, i tried to modified again but it not work.